Cannot read excel file in Pandas as required

I am learning stack()/ unstack() in Pandas
Link to the excel file is here.  The data in the file looks as under:



My code is as under:
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.read_excel("stocks.xlsx",header=[0,1]) # on local machine
   df 


The output looks as under:




The required output is as under:


The question:

Why am I not getting the required output?  What is wrong with code?

Since I am not getting required output, I cannot work further on the data.

Please guide me.  Thanks.



df = pd.read_excel("stocks.xlsx", index_col=0, header=[0,1])

Thank you Panda Kim.  I have already tried the above line, which does not give result as per point no.5 given above.

If what Panda Kim is saying does not work for you, can you elaborate what you expect more in your answer?

You are producing multi-index columns as needed for that Excel format. So the top -level price label relates to all of the next level Facebook, Google, and Microsoft labelled columns.  The multi-index can then be used for access as required. So as others said what are you having problems with doing?
